# nothing is linking with html in hosting

Tags: html, web-hosting, public-html

My `index.html` file is in the `public_html` directory. All css files/ image files are in a css directory, and images directory respectively.

I have been over and over my code but the index is not linking with anything in hosting. 
`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">   // ***
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-icon.css">`
```

*** I moved the `main.cs`s file directly into `public_html` to see if it would work and it does. I can only assume that I have made a mistake in my path.

BTW I have added a / to the css path in `href`. I don't want to move everything into the `public_html` folder, which I am taking to be the root

Many thanks

Comment: The main.css file will now link to index.html

Comment: As long as the rest of the CSS files are in the structure `public_html/css/*****.css` then it should work. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Add at least 1) used webserver 2) operating system 3) error code returned by the webserver on these files 4) any relevant entries in the server's logfiles . Also, are css and images subdirctories of the public_html dir (which seems to function properly as main.html is served correctly)

Comment: @murphyMe Please add your complete directory structure to your question so we see the necessary relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be redundant but one possible workaround is to use `./` everywhere. Eg.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/flexslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">   // ***
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/font-icon.css">
```

It should work.

Assuming the `css` folder and `main.css` are the siblings of the HTML file in which this code is inserted .

Comment: Thanks for your help @Abhilash . This did help. Sorry that I didn't respond sooner